# How to run IBM DB2 bind command on remote server through Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, db2, bind

I have a playbook, as below, to bind an IBM DB2 SQL:

```yaml
tasks:
- name: IBM DB2 bind a program_A
  win_command: 'D:test\db2BindJob.cmd'
  become: yes
  become_user: db2_admin
```

and below 2 cmd files are all on Ansible managed node (Windows Server 2012)

*db2BindJob.cmd*

```
@echo off
CD C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN
db2cmd D:\test\db2bind.cmd
```

*db2bind.cmd*

```
db2 connect reset
db2 connect to DB_X user user_name using user_pwd
db2 bind D:\test\program_A.bnd isolation ur datetime iso collection TEST grant public
db2 connect reset
```

I run this playbook successfully without any error message `(ok=2, ..., failed=0, ...)`
but the `program_A.bnd` has **not** been bound into `DB_X` (in other words, bind failed, not in effect).

I also tired to replace `win_command` by `win_shell`, but, it still failed to bind `program_A.bnd` through Ansible playbook.

When I try to open a command window on the managed node to run `D:\test\db2BindJob.cmd` directly, then,
the `program_A.bnd` was successfully bound to `DB_X`.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is the Db2 environment correctly set for Ansible on the remote machine? Could you run a simple connect from within the job?

Comment: Does Ansible keep a log file showing both the stdout and the stderr from the batch file(s)??  Your batch files have zero error checking, they do not verify that their pre-reqs are in place, or that any single command completes without error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Change "**db2cmd D:\test\db2bind.cmd**" to "**db2cmd -i D:\test\db2bind.cmd**" and it works! (Execute db2cmd command following the **-i** option while sharing the same DB2 command window and inheriting file handles)